# Как последовательно считывать данные json файла и отдавать в форму?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, form

Есть интерфес опросника, который работает без перезагрузки страницы и данные которые берутся из `json` файла.
Вариант с одним вопросом реализован, сложности начинаются, когда вопросов много в цепочке один за другим.
Как сделать так, чтобы считывать данные из `json` файла в массив и последовательно отдавать после нажатия на кнопку ответить очередного вопроса?

Собираю массив через

```
data.forEach(function(item) {});
```

, но если внутрь поместить функцию **answers**, то абсолютно все ответы ждя разных вопросов просто отобразятся на одной страницы. 
Как можно реализовать задуманное?

Фидл здесь - http://jsfiddle.net/qxrognd6/

```js
$(function() {
  var vote = {};
  $('#ok').click(function() {

    $.get(poll.json, function(data) {

      // фактически данные poll.json хранятся в таком виде
      //data = [{"id":"1", "question":"Какую марку предпочитаете?", "answers":["honda", "bmw", "volvo"]}, {"id":"2", "question":"Цвет авто?", "answers":["black", "red", "blue"]}

      data.forEach(function(item) {

        vote.id = item.id;
        vote.question = item.question;
        vote.answers = item.answers;

      });

      answers();
    });

    appearance('#start', '#content');
    return false;

  });

  var appearance = function(slide, content) {
    $(slide).hide('fast', showNewContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');

    function showNewContent() {
      $(content).show('normal', hideLoader());
    }

    function hideLoader() {
      $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
  };
  var answers = function() {
    var form = $('#vote');
    var answers = form.find('.answers');
    form.parent().find('.question').text(vote['question']);
    for (var i = 0; i <= vote['answers'].length - 1; i++) {
      answers.append('<div class="radio">' +
        '<label>' +
        '<input type="radio" name="poll" value="' + (i + 1) + '">' +
        vote['answers'][i] +
        '</label>' +
        '</div>');
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}

#load {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 11px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start">
  <a id='ok' href=''>Поехали</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h4 class="question">Вопрос</h4>
  <form id="vote" action="vote.php" method="POST">
    <div class="answers"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ответить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: что у вас `answers` в функции `answers`?

Comment: имею ввиду вот это `answers.append('<div class="radio">...`

Comment: @mix ой, прошу прощения, не дописал 3 строчки кода. исправился

Comment: `var answers = function() {`  и  `answers.append(` - что такое `answers`?

Comment: @Igor а, вы имеете ввиду название функции? `var answers = function() {}` - это функция ответов на вопрос, которая к каждому вызывается, а `answers.append(` - это сами строковые переменные, которые дописываются в саму форму. Надеюсь, так будет понятнее

Comment: что вы в итоге отправляете(планируете отправить) на `vote.php`?

Comment: Планирую отправлять ответ, который выбрал пользователь из предложенных ему радиобаттонов